# Why does convergence in distribution not imply convergence in mean square sense?

Tags: probability-theory

I know convergence in mean square sense implies convergence in distribution. But a distribution defines the moments of the random variable. Given the convergence in distribution, why don't we observe convergence in the moments? Should not the reverse also hold going by this logic?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- Convergence in mean square (also called convergence in $L^2$) doesn't mean that $\mathbb{E}X^2_n\rightarrow \mathbb{E}X^2$ but that $\mathbb{E}\left(X-X_n\right)^2\rightarrow 0$ (equivalently: $\lVert X-X_n\rVert_2=\sqrt{\mathbb{E}(X-X_n)^2}\rightarrow 0$). One implication of this is that moments converge (as a consequence of the reverse triangular inequality), but it is also stronger because it says that the expected square distance between the sequence and its limit goes to $0$.
- Convergence in distribution doesn't imply convergence of the moments. A classic counterexample is to take for all $n\geq 0$ the random variable $X_n$ with $\mathbb{P}(X_n=2^n)=2^{-n}$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_n=0)=1-2^{-n}$. It can be shown that this sequence converges in probability (therefore in distribution) to $0$ but for all $n\geq 0$ we have $\mathbb{E}X_n=1\neq 0$. Note that, by the first point, this means that $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ does not converge to $0$ in $L^2$.